# Excel - list comments then hyperlink to original comments

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, hyperlink, comments

I used the code listed in this post below including one extra line in comment within the same post to add the hyperlink. However, the hyperlink only works when the tab name has no space in it (i.e., TabOne, TabTwo,..). If the tab name has space (i.e., Tab One, Tab Two), then it will show "Invalid reference" when clicking on the hyperlink. How do I fix it?

[VBA Code](https://superuser.com/questions/1532328/excel-list-comments-then-hyperlink-to-original-comment-location)

Comment: `CS.Hyperlinks.Add CS.Range("A1").Offset(NextRow, 4), "", "'" & Sht.Name & "'!" & Comment_.Parent.Address`

Answer (score 0):

Excel's hyperlink function works a bit strangely. Even if you have spaces or special characters in the filename, hyperlink does not want single quotes in the file part [...] of the reference, but if you have spaces in the sheet name, then yes add those in single quotes eg. `"'" & sheetname & "'"`. Worst still if you are using e.g. the CELL function to determine the address/URL/path to a cell, CELL will return the address with single quotes if it contains spaces or special characters. Most of Excel doesn't mind these quotes if you use it with say INDIRECT but unfortunately HYPERLINK does. You can remove these with `=SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address", Sheet1!A1), "'", "") but painfully, if your sheet name does contain spaces, you must have the sheet name in single quotes but not the filename for HYPERLINK to work. Easy way out, just don't use spaces in sheet names and filenames

Also see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1734768/how-to-add-a-hyperlink-to-a-outputted-value-to-link-it-its-source/1734837) related question, especially the comments.

Comment: Thank you! It works!!!

Comment: Kindly checkmark the solution thanks!